# Chain of terraform resources syntax

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a module main.tf for azurerm_kubernetes_cluster and azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool with below code. dev1.tfvars with variable values. I want to use kubernetes_cluster_id from first kubernets value. I tried couple of values but confused as know little about terraform. I am getting error
kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.DEV-AKS-11.name
A managed resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" has not been declared in module.AKS.

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "AKS" {
  for_each            = var.AKS
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resourceGroupName
  dns_prefix          = each.value.dnsprefix
  node_resource_group = each.value.noderesourcegroup



  default_node_pool {
    name       = each.value.nodename
    node_count = each.value.nodecount
    vm_size    = each.value.vmsize
  }

identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  

}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "nodepool" {
  for_each              = var.nodepool
  name                  = each.value.nodepoolname
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.DEV-AKS-11.id
  vm_size               = each.value.nodepoolvmsize
  node_count            = each.value.nodepoolcount
  enable_auto_scaling   = each.value.nodepoolenableautoscaling
}
```

**dev1.tfvars**

```
AKS = { 
    "DEV-AKS-11" = {
        name     = "DEV-AKS-11"
        location = "UK South"
        resourceGroupName = "DEV-RG-11"
        dnsprefix = "devaks11"
        nodename = "testnode"
        nodecount = "1"
        vmsize = "Standard_D2_v2"
        noderesourcegroup = "DEV-RG-AKS-11"


  }
}

nodepool = { 
    "agentpool" = {
        name     = "agentpool"
        nodepoolvmsize = "Standard_D2_v2"
        nodepoolcount = "1"
        nodepoolenableautoscaling = "false"
        nodepoolmode = "system"
        
  }

  "appspool" = {
        name     = "appspool"
        nodepoolvmsize = "Standard_D2_v2"
        nodepoolcount = "1"
        nodepoolenableautoscaling = "false"
        nodepoolmode = "user"
        
  }

  "minappspool" = {
        name     = "minappspool"
        nodepoolvmsize = "Standard_D2_v2"
        nodepoolcount = "1"
        nodepoolenableautoscaling = "false"
        nodepoolmode = "user"
        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reference the value using the key for that map.

```
kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.AKS["DEV-AKS-11"].id
```

dot notation will not work here.

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "AKS" {
  for_each            = var.AKS
```

In the state file under azurerm_kubernetes_cluster AKS there will be a set of keys and values, these keys will match the keys of the map you iterated over to create the resources. So you must access the resource via the key.

Comment: The resource name also doesn't match: the declaration says `AKS` but the reference says `aks`. You are right about the instance key syntax but the resource name must also match for this to work properly.

Comment: I have fixed this in the answer now